# VLC 2.1.5 - unable to find file caching values in preferences

Tags: vlc-media-player, cache, lag

I'm having some lag when playing videos over my network with VLC 2.1.5. I have plenty of bandwidth. I read that I should increase the caching values under Input/Codecs-Access modules-File, but the setting is not there. I could not find the setting anywhere else as I searched through the menus.

Would someone please tell me where the "extra network caching value" is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VLC's streaming features, and I'm running 2.0.5 not 2.1.5, but I believe this is what you are looking for.

[image: VLC Streaming Settings]

Go to "media", "stream", the tab "Network", click "Show more options", and choose your desired caching amount either using the caching form or the edit options.

Comment: This adds a flag for overriding the default value. The other answer is a persistable solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can config caching on Tools -> preferences (show settings "All") -> Input / Codecs.
In Advanced option, define your preferences for caching.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.