# Changing cache for files in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I understand how to change cache for files in VLC but I can't find a way to save this new setting.  Every time I restart VLC it goes to 500. I have a version 2.1.5 of VLC.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your cache like explained in:
 [VLC 2.1.5 - unable to find file caching values in preferences](https://superuser.com/questions/809020/vlc-2-1-5-unable-to-find-file-caching-values-in-preferences/865178#865178)
Save your new configuration after changing them.